# Ask WP-CLI latest core WordPress version released

Tags: wp-cli

I'm trying to make a script (bash) that examines all WordPress installations on my server and returns a set of information. I would need to know the latest known version of WordPress (official repository), can you do it via WP-CLI? or is there another way (API...)?

(I'm looking for a WP-CLI solution)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting version number of latest Wordpress release](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176870/getting-version-number-of-latest-wordpress-release)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wp core version`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/version/) displays your current WordPress version.

```
$ wp core version
5.2.4
```

Adding `--extra` shows extended version information.

```
$ wp core version --extra
WordPress version: 5.2.4
Database revision: 44719
TinyMCE version:   4.940 (4940-20190515)
Package language:  en_US
```

[`wp core check-update`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/check-update/) lists the most recent versions when there are updates available, or success message when up to date.

```
$ wp core check-update --field=version
5.3
```